# AWS License Manager "SignedToken" is missing, how can I get it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

According to the following AWS documentation:

- [1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/license-manager/checkout-license.html
- [2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/license-manager/latest/userguide/license-signing.html
- [3] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/license-manager/latest/APIReference/API_CheckoutLicense.html#API_CheckoutLicense_ResponseSyntax

I should be receiving an element called "SignedToken", however after many attempts with using the `aws license-manager checkout-license` command and the C++ AWS SDK, this one field is always missing. I've made a test license, and attached an asymmetric key (in sign/verify configuration) to the license. However link [2] says to use a "customer master key" (CMK) which doesn't appear to be a term that's used anywhere else in the AWS docs (maybe its the same as customer managed key?). Is there more to it then just calling the CheckoutLicense action to get this "SignedToken"? I'm also curious what can I do with the "SignedToken" once I get it? The description in link [1] for "SignedToken" is just "Signed token". Signed with what exactly, and what "token" did they sign? My goal is to just verify the license I get from CheckoutLicense in my application.

For example I've tried this with AWS CLI:

```
aws license-manager checkout-license \
        --product-sku MEOW15908721395 \
        --checkout-type PROVISIONAL \
        --key-fingerprint "aws:<aws-id>:Meow Industries:issuer-fingerprint" \
        --entitlements "Name=Entitlement1,Value=1,Unit=Count" \
        --client-token $(uuidgen)
```

which prints out

```
{
    "CheckoutType": "PROVISIONAL",
    "LicenseConsumptionToken": "260e189162e94521817761f577174168",
    "EntitlementsAllowed": [
        {
            "Name": "Entitlement1",
            "Value": "1",
            "Unit": "Count"
        }
    ],
    "IssuedAt": "2023-08-03T21:58:56",
    "Expiration": "2023-08-03T22:58:56",
    "LicenseArn": "arn:aws:license-manager::<aws-id>:license:l-67ebd558fbe94822ae9ddbde64955c7a"
}
```

I've written the equivalent code in C++ using the AWS SDK, and GetSignedToken() returns an empty string.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!